# Header-footer-content layout with inline-block div taking remaining space (no float or overflow: hidden)

Tags: css, html

I have a (relatively) simple layout, with fixed header and footer divs. The content div is split in two "full height" divs with `display: inline-block;`. The left div is used for navigation and the right one for the actual content and has `overflow-y: scroll;`. The problem is that I cannot set the width of the right div to fill the remaining space. I have tried using *float* (as a last resort) but the right div was pushed downwards and, honestly, I'd prefer not to use floats.

Is filling the remaining width possible in my scenario? I would very much like to not hardcode the width of the right div.

Here's the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pgyt6/).

Simple HTML structure:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">This is the header area.</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftContent">&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="textContent">
            <p>Hello world (and other content)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">This is the footer area.</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS excerpt:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }

#container { position:relative; margin:0 auto; width:750px; overflow:hidden;
             height:auto !important; height:100%; min-height:100%; }

#header { border-bottom:1px solid black; height:30px; }

#content { position:absolute; top:31px; bottom:30px; overflow-y:none; width:100%; }

#leftContent { display:inline-block; height:100%; width:200px;
              border-right:1px solid black; vertical-align:top; }

#textContent { display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:top; overflow-y:scroll;
              width:540px; /*would like to not have it hardcoded*/ }

#footer { position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0; height:30px; }
```

**Edit**:

Thanks to [Prasanth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21847870/1679011), I was able to achieve what I wanted. The solution was to set

1. `display:flex; flex-direction:row;` on the `#content` div and
2. `width: 100%;` on the `#textContent` div.

<del>Testing on IE 11 (and downwards in compatibility mode) did not produce unwanted results.</del>* The new version can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A5NGL/).

*Edit: This method works properly in IE11. In IE10, the scrollbars do not appear if the content of the `#content` div requires scrolling. The layout works thought. In IE <10 it does not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox** to achieve this

Go through [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and you will get what you need

```
.content{ display:flex  } .content > div { flex: 1 auto; }
```

and beware of browser support